# Adding versus multiplying identical photons' wavefunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, bosons

I am currently confused with understanding many identical photons' wavefunctions. I think that photon wavefunctions are supposed to be multiplied together to describe the total state of all bosons. However, through some magic I am confused with, the total boson wavefunction must yield a field strength proportional to the sum of all of the boson wavefunctions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Multiplying the wavefunctions" is a pretty nebulous term. Let's work with some definite vocabulary here, shall we?

$(1)$ The states of one QM particle are elements of some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. If we care only about position on a line as completely defining the state (which we can for a scalar boson), i.e. demand that the space be spanned by the orthogonal position basis $|x\rangle,x\in \mathbb{R}$, this space is isomorphic to the square integrable functions $\psi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by sending arbitrary states $|\psi\rangle$ to the function $\psi(x) = \langle \psi | x \rangle$. [We have ignored some technicalities above, i.e. normalization, Gelfand tripel, distribution...and we will continue to ignore them, they don't matter for this argument]

$(2)$ The states of $N$ such particles is given by the $N$-fold [tensor product space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) $\mathcal{H} \otimes \dots \otimes \mathcal{H}$. It's basis is formally given by

$$|x_1,\dots,x_N\rangle :=|x_1\rangle \otimes \dots \otimes |x_N\rangle, x_i \in \mathbb{R} \forall i \in \{1,\dots,N\}$$

We can map any state $|\psi\rangle \in \bigotimes_{i = 1}^N \mathcal{H}$ to a wavefunction again by

$$ \psi : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{C} , (x_1,\dots,x_N) \mapsto \langle \psi |x_1,\dots,x_N\rangle$$

This can only be written as $\langle\psi_1|x_1\rangle\dots\langle\psi_N|x_N\rangle = \prod_i \psi_i(x_i)$ if the state $\psi$ is a state constructed from the single states $|\psi_i\rangle$ of the particles as $|\psi\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle \otimes \dots \otimes |\psi_N\rangle$. **Not all states in** $\bigotimes_{i = 1}^N \mathcal{H}$ **can be written that way**.

So, if you indeed know all individual states, the total wavefunction is indeed a multiple of the single wavefunctions. However, for so-called *entangled states*, this is impossible.

So, taking the tensor product is *multiplying the wavefunctions*, which enlarges the space of all possible states. *Adding the wavefunctions* is just using the addition on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. It does not enlarge the space of states, it only superposes two states of the **same** particle/system.

I have no idea what "field strength" you are talking about in the OP, though.

Comment: *Where did you get that claim from*? The QM wavefunction of a boson is just a complex number, or, when squared, a probability amplitude. How would you ever relate that to the EM field without quantizing the gauge field in a QFT style?

Comment: I apologize. I was referring to the energy density of the classical electromagnetic $E^2+B^2$ when I wrote field strength.

Comment: The best name I can come up with is the field strength operator $\boldsymbol{A}$ found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field ?

Comment: @linuxfreebird: That, while being quantization of the EM field, has nothing directly to do with the ordinary boson wavefunctions one usually looks at in QFT, so I am a bit at a loss where you derive your statement *"However, through some magic I am confused with, the total boson wavefunction must yield a field strength proportional to the sum of all of the boson wavefunctions?"* from.

Comment: The square of the expectation values of $\boldsymbol{E}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ yields the sum of the square of the individual field operators of different states?

Comment: You only get these operators when you consider a field theory, i.e. you make particle creation and annihiliation possible by making the field an operator *and not* the position/momentum anymore. That's a whole different story and has nothing to do with pure many-particle QM. I still don't get why you would insist on that. Could you define the operator $\vec E$ or $\vec B$ for the space $\mathcal{H}$ I constructed above as the building block of QM bosons?

Comment: I apologize. I am not sure if your question " Could you define the operator E⃗  or B⃗  for the space H I constructed above as the building block of QM bosons?" is rhetorical or a question of curiosity. I am interested in investigating that question.

Comment: Don't be sorry for trying to learn! The question is a mixture of both. I don't think you can, but if you could, I could answer (or, first, understand) your question. If you can't, you should realize that somewhere in your understanding of EM and wavefunctions and all that something got mixed up because the question as you are asking it then does not make sense.